# Laurent Series of $f(z) = \frac{z}{\sinh(z)}$ in the region $ 4 < |z| <5 $

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, hyperbolic-functions

Determine all coefficients, belonging to $ z^n $ with $ n<5 $, of the Laurent series of the function $f(z)=\frac{z}{\sinh(z)}$ in the region $4 < |z| <5 $.

Could someone help me to find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sinh(z)$ has simple zeroes at $z\in \pi i \mathbb{Z}$, hence $f(z)=\frac{z}{\sinh z}$ is regular at $z=0$ but has two simple poles at $z=\pm \pi i$, having residues $\mp \pi i$. So we have that:
$$ g(z) = f(z)-\frac{2\pi^2}{\pi^2+z^2} $$
is a holomorphic function over $|z|<2\pi$. By computing its Taylor series we have:
$$ g(z) = -1+\left(\frac{2}{\pi^2}-\frac{1}{6}\right)z^2+\left(\frac{7}{360}-\frac{2}{\pi ^4}\right)z^4 +O(z^6)$$
so the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ over $4<|z|<5$ is given by:
$$ f(z) = 2\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^{m+1}\frac{\pi^{2m}}{z^{2m}}+(-1)+\left(\frac{2}{\pi^2}-\frac{1}{6}\right)z^2+\left(\frac{7}{360}-\frac{2}{\pi ^4}\right)z^4 +O(z^6).$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but could you please elaborate on how you found the function $ g(z) $?

Comment: @SBuysse: it is just $f(z)$ minus the singular part inside $|z|<4$. Since the poles at $z=\pm \pi i$ are simple and they have residues $\mp \pi i$, the singular part is given by: $$\frac{-\pi i}{z-\pi i}+\frac{\pi i}{z+\pi i}=\frac{2\pi^2}{\pi^2+z^2}.$$

Comment: I fully understand your thought process to solve this problem. The only thing that is bothering me is the 'long' process to determine $a_2 = \frac{2}{\pi^2}-\frac{1}{6}$ and $a_4=\frac{7}{360}-\frac{2}{\pi^4}$ without the aid of software. Is there another way to determine those coefficients?